# sculpting problem with eyelids

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I was sculpting a human head and when I made the eyelids I noticed there are some random black lines and circles at random places on the head.  I tried smoothing out these lines but that hasn't worked and I have tried different methods to sculpt the eyelids but the same result always occurs,  Does anyone know how to avoid or remove these random black lines?  Here is the head I made.  [image]